# How to convert a list by mapping an element into multiple elements in python?

Tags: python

For example,
how to convert [1, 5, 7] into [1,2,5,6,7,8] into python?
[x, x+1 for x in [1,5,7]] can't work for sure...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I would do:

```
l = [1, 5, 7]
print([y for x in l for y in (x, x + 1)])
```

Another way using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
l = [1, 5, 7]
print(list(chain.from_iterable((x, x + 1) for x in l)))
```

Answer (score 2):

And you can always overcomplicate the problem with [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html), [`imap()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap), [`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), [`izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) and [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip, imap
>>> from operator import add
>>> from functools import partial
>>> 
>>> l = [1, 5, 7]
>>>
>>> list(chain(*izip(l, imap(partial(add, 1), l))))
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

What happens here:

- we make an iterator over `l` that applies an [`add` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add) with `1` as an argument
- we zip the initial list with the iterator returned by `imap()` to produce pairs of x, x+1 values
- we [flatten the list with `chain()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/771848) and convert it to the list to see the result

Comment: Haha this is hideous ;)

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the downvote though. This is a working solution *with an explanation*, links to docs and it even says I understand this is an over-complication of a sort.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to think about the problem is to make a second list of incremented values and add it to the original list, then sort it:

```
l = [1, 5, 7]
m = l + [i+1 for i in l]
m.sort()
print m  # [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine some ideas from alecxe's answer and what you already had:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> a = [1, 5, 7]
>>> b = ((x, x+1) for x in a)
>>> 
>>> list(itertools.chain(*b))
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

What I have done is :

1. Define in `b` a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) which allows us to have (something that looks like) a tuple that would have looked like `((1, 2), (5, 6), (7, 8))` but without evaluating it right away. It would have also worked with a list comprehension.
2. [Unpack `b` in the argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) of itertools.chain(). It would be the equivalent of `itertools.chain((1, 2), (5, 6), (7, 8))`. That function concatenates its arguments.
3. Use list() to create a list from the return value of the `itertools.chain()` function since it's an iterator.

This could also have worked without any intermediate step:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*((x, x+1) for x in [1, 5, 7])))
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

But "Simple is better than complex"

I hope this helps.

I would have put more links if I had more reputation, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Make a generator function that iterates over the list and yields, in turn, each element and that element plus one.  Iterate over your generator.

```
def foo(lyst):
    for element in lyst:
        yield element
        yield element + 1

>>> print(list(foo([1, 5, 7])))
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> 
>>> print([element for element in foo([1, 5, 7])])
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do your list comprehension logic with tuples and then flatten the resulting list:

`[n for pair in [(x, x+1) for x in [1,5,7]] for n in pair]`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fill the list with the numbers between the min and max+1 values you can use `[i for i in range (min(x),max(x)+2)]` assuming `x` is your list.

Comment: Don't think that's what they're trying to achieve.